# How would i use a for loop to display an list of numbers as the output?

Tags: python, api, loops, listview, jupyter-notebook

I recently came across this website using api to call a company and display the company numbers as an output. I used this as a basis and then was trying to use one specific company number where each time the code loops the number adds 1. How would I be able to do this at the moment the display is random numbers, any help would be great thank you?
For example, currently, the code runs and displays a number of random numbers i want it to display numbers starting from 09628955 then adding 1 to that number 09628956,09628957 etc.

ComapnySICS.py file

```py
df = pd.read_csv(company_numbers_file)
ch_api = CompaniesHouseService("API KEY")
tic = datetime.datetime.now()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    company_number = row["Company Number"]
    ch_profile = ch_api.get_company_profile(company_number)
    df.at[index, "Company Name"] = ch_profile.get("company_name", None)

    sics = ch_profile.get("sic_codes", [None])
    for i in range(0,len(sics)):
        df.at[index, f"SIC {i+1}"] = sics[i]

    print(f"Number: {row['Company Number']} | "\
          f"Name: {df.at[index,'Company Name']}")
    
#End timer
toc = datetime.datetime.now()

avg_time = ((toc-tic).total_seconds())/(len(df.index)-1)
print(f"Average time between API calls: {avg_time:0.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: 1. Could you reduce your code to a [mre]? I don't really understand (yet) what you want to do 2. Consider removing your keys - they look like they should be a secret. Instead load the data manually, and show an excerpt of the data in your post.

Comment: Sure thing I think this is better right... also using this website to base it off https://www.pythonontoast.com/python-data-interface-companies-house/

Comment: Do you just want to have a display of number starting at `row['CompanyNumber']` and then increase this number in a loop?

Comment: Yes that's it so displays the number row[CompanyNumber] as 09628955  then plus 1 to this number. Increase by 1 in the loop

Comment: If anyone has any help on this it would be great I have 2 python files this one is the company SICS and the other is ComapniesHouseService which CompanySICS is importing the information from the other file